# Lower limit for NLME regression

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-regression

I am using NLME packege in R to perform non linear regression.

The aim of the model is to estimate parameters related with gaseous weight loss from different silages.

I have defined my function as:

```
profileLag <- function(Day,B,C,L) {B*(1-exp(-C*(Day-L)))}
```

B is the asymptote = total weight loss, C represents fractional rate of weight loss per day and L is the lagtime prior to onset of fermentation

I would like to add a lower bound to my parameter L (lagtime before onset of fermentation).

I should be able to do this by:

```
nlme(....control=nlmeControl(opt="nlminb",lower=c(B=-Inf,C=-Inf,L=0)))
```

However, this does not work. I do not get any error messages, the limits are just simply ignored by the model.

Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can fix it/add limits to my L parameter?

I have build my model as follows:

```
#First model with estimated start values
GWL.DM.F2.M1<-nlme(GWL_g_kgDM~profileLag(Day,B,C,L),data=GWL.F2.grp,fixed=list(B~1,C~1,L~1),
random=pdDiag(B+C+L~1),correlation=corAR1(0.8,form=~Day|BagIDuq),
start=c(B=160,C=0.05,L=0))

# Second model - heterogeneous variance
GWL.DM.F2.M2<- update(GWL.DM.F2.M1,weights=varIdent(form=~1|MixID))

# Fixed effects from second model (new start values)
fe2.F2<-fixef(GWL.DM.F2.M2)

# Final model - parameters depend on type of silage (MixID)
GWL.DM.F2.M3<-update(GWL.DM.F2.M2,fixed=list(B~MixID-1,C~MixID-1,L~MixID-1),
start=c(B=rep(fe2.F2["B"],4),C=rep(fe2.F2["C"],4),L=rep(fe2.F2["L"],4)))
```

The limits should be added to the final model. I have also tired adding it to the first and second model and to the two other parameters (just to check), but they are always ignored by the model.

In the final model the limits should be added as:

```
nlme(....control=nlmeControl(opt="nlminb",lower=c(B=rep(-Inf,4),C=rep(-Inf,4),L=rep(0,4))))
```